# How to convert to laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel

Can you give me a little bit of help with this?I want to convert this for laravel 5.2, and also add `role_users` table with column `user_id` and `user_role`. Can you help me please?

```
$career_solutions_data = DB::select("
    SELECT 
    career_solutions.id, 
    career_solutions.subject, 
    career_solutions.date, 
    career_solutions.public, 
    career_solutions.views, 
    career_solutions.optional, 
    career_solutions.on_offer, 
    users.username, 
    users.profile_picture, 
    categories.category, 
    categories.category_url,
    categories.color, 
    career_solutions_categories.category as sub_category 

    FROM career_solutions 

    INNER JOIN categories 
        ON categories.id = career_solutions.topic_category_id 

    INNER JOIN career_solutions_categories 
        ON career_solutions_categories.id = career_solutions.topic_subcategory_id 

    INNER JOIN users 
        ON users.id = career_solutions.user_id 

    INNER JOIN privacy_settings 
        ON privacy_settings.user_id = users.id 

    WHERE users.deleted_at IS NULL 
    AND (
            (privacy_settings.career_solutions = 0 AND public = 1 ) 
            OR (users.id IN (

                SELECT contacts.contact_id 
                FROM contacts 
                WHERE contacts.user_id = $id
                )
            )
        ) 

    OR users.id = $id

    ORDER BY date desc limit 5000
");
```

Comment: Have you tried a little simpler query first and then worked your way to this larger one?

Comment: It s not my code, and I want to make it easier to read...Because I can't / don't know how to add another table to this query and I need a little help with .

Comment: Have you tried building and learning some less advanced query first? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries I have linked the documentation for Laravel, maybe if you go explore the framework first and come back here when youre comfortable with the framework. Also take a look at sql joins

Comment: I've reformatted the query for ease of legibility but the additional spaces would be superfluous in the code - especially as it's in a `DB::select()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on this, and it likely doesn't work.

BUT - it will give you a good start point on rebuilding this query in Eloquent.

There's probably a better way of doing this, but again, this is more for a starting point. You really should be trying to learn Eloquent better as it's a pretty powerful and fluent ORM. (It reads so much better than T-SQL!).

But it'll look something along these lines anyways:

```php
CareerSolutions::with(
    [
        'categories',
        'categories.career_solutions_categories',
        'users',
        'users.privacy_settings'
    ], function($query) {
        $query->where('users.privacy_settings.career_solutions', 0);
        $query->where('users.privacy_settings.public', 1);
        $query->orWhereIn('contacts.contact_id', function() {
            Contact::where('user_id', $id)->pluck('id');
        });
    }
)->orWhere('users.id', $id)->get();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. So, should I try to learn Eloquent method?

Comment: Yes. Laracasts probably have some good resources for learning eloquent.